# Command to check openflow version

Tags: openflow

I Installed mininet in Ubuntu system, By default openflow also installing with mininet. But how can I know the installed version of openflow?

Answer (score 0):

`openflow` appears to be provided by `openvswitch-controller`; `apt-cache policy openvswitch-controller` should show you the version installed.

Comment: This does not work if you compiled openvswitch code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The version of openvswitch can be determined with `ovs−ctl version`, but that won't necessarily tell you the version of "OpenFlow" that is supported by that version. To do that, you'll need to cross reference it against the openvswitch web site or source. Per http://git.openvswitch.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=openvswitch;a=blob_plain;f=FAQ;hb=HEAD:

> Open vSwitch 1.9 and earlier support only OpenFlow 1.0 (plus extensions that bring in many of the features from later versions of OpenFlow).
>
> Open vSwitch 1.10 and later have experimental support for OpenFlow
>      1.2 and 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command to show the version of openflow being run. I am using openvswitch v2.17

```
$ovs-ofctl -V
ovs-ofctl (Open vSwitch) 2.17.2
OpenFlow versions 0x1:0x6
```

`0x1:0x6` = "1.6"

http://fosshelp.blogspot.com/2014/10/how-to-find-openvswitch-and-openflow.html